# Is it possible that FIRST SET contains same terminal more than one time

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, automata

I am confused that can FIRST SET contains same terminal twice..
for example I have grammar

```
E->T+E|T   FIRST(E)={a,a}
T->a   FIRST(T)={a}
..
```

Is this correct? or I should write

```
FIRST(E)={a}
```

Comment: FIRST is a set. You only write each element in the set once. So, `FIRST(E) = FIRST(T+E) ∪ FIRST(T) = FIRST(T) ∪ FIRST(T) = FIRST(T) = {a}`.

Answer (score 0):

By definition sets can not contain the same element multiple times - this applies to first sets as much as any other set. So `{a}` is the proper way to write it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to compute the First and Follow sets, to construct the final predictive table, but generally, you need to resolve all the conflicts first, which are:

```
ε-derivation
Direct Left Recursion
Indirect Left Recursion
Ambiguous prefixes
```

In your example (Or part of it, I guess), you need to factor out ambiguous prefixes, the T.

```
E  -> T E'
E' -> + E | ε
T  -> a
```

Formally, for any non-terminal with derivation rules of the form A → αβ | αγ

```
1- Remove these 2 derivation rules
2- Create a rule A′ → β | γ
3- Create a rule A → α A′
```

Check out this [Paper about Conflicts](https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/%7Ecomp171/wiki.files/ps5.pdf), it was very helpful for me, and you might as well check this [slide](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/lectures/03/Slides03.pdf) and [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/lectures/04/Slides04A.pdf), if you have any problem with top-down parsing.